# Can I press the return key using code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a uitextfield and I count the number of characters. The idea is that when the count reaches four then it should go on to the next textfield.  The problem is that while the counter tells me that the field does contain four characters the field only shows three characters. It works when I manually press the return key but I don't the user to have to do this. Here's my code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSInteger textLength = 0;
    textLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSLog(@"Length: %ld", (long)textLength);
    NSLog(@"tag: %ld", (long)textField.tag);
    if (textField.tag == 1 || textField.tag == 2) {
        if (textLength == 4) {
            NSLog(@"doneeee");
            NSLog(@"testfield: %@", textField.text);
           }
    }

  if (textField.tag == 3) {
            NSLog(@"we're here");
            if (textLength == 6) {
                NSLog(@"Zip is done");
                [self checkTheTextField:textField];
        }
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the on-screen field only showing three characters, or the NSLog? The NSLog is called before the method has returned YES, which means that they latest change has not been applied yet (textField.text refers to what HAS changed, not what SHOULD change). When reaching 4, you should be able to call [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]; and then [yourNewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Following up what @jorn said, you'd need to call [yourNewTextField becomeFirstResponder] after this method returns YES in order to see that 4th character show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another option, when the length hits 4 you can just set the textField.text directly, set the next textField as first responder, and return NO.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (textField.tag == 1 || textField.tag == 2) {
        if (text.length == 4) {
            textField.text = text;
            [yourNewTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    // ...

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder` when text length is 4

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment, the reason you're only seeing 3 characters being printed out in your `NSLog` statement is because the changes haven't been applied to `textField.text` until the method returns `YES`. In order to have the application automatically select the next text field when the desired length is reached, you just need to call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next text field. For instance:

```
if(textLength == 4)
{
    NSLog(@"doneeee");

    // Here's how you can output the field's text, assuming you will return YES
    NSLog(@"testfield: %@", [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // Here's how you make the next field active
    [nextTextFieldOutlet becomeFirstResponder];  // Or whatever you field is called.
}

return YES;
```

---

As a side note, you may want to put in some logic to return `NO` from this method if the field's length is *greater* than your desired length for the particular field. For instance, if you only want a max of 6 for your postal code field, check if the `fieldLength > 6` and return `NO` in that case. That way, if someone tries to paste in a long string, it will reject it.